# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.svm._classes'

Tags: python, flask, scikit-learn, pickle, sklearn-pandas

I have created a model for breast cancer prediction. Now I want to deploy my model on a UI, for that I am using flask. To connect the model, I made .pkl file of the model but when I am trying to read the file through my app.py, it is giving me an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.svm._classes'
What should I do in order to run my app.py?

Here is my app.py:

```
from flask import Flask,send_from_directory,render_template, request, url_for, redirect
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from package.patient import Patients, Patient
from package.doctor import Doctors, Doctor
from package.appointment import Appointments, Appointment
from package.common import Common
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np


with open('config.json') as data_file:
    config = json.load(data_file)

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(Patients, '/patient')
api.add_resource(Patient, '/patient/<int:id>')
api.add_resource(Doctors, '/doctor')
api.add_resource(Doctor, '/doctor/<int:id>')
api.add_resource(Appointments, '/appointment')
api.add_resource(Appointment, '/appointment/<int:id>')
api.add_resource(Common, '/common')



model_breast=pickle.load(open('model_breast.pkl','rb'))

# Routes

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST','GET'])
def predict():
    int_features=[int(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    final=[np.array(int_features)]
    print(int_features)
    print(final)
    prediction=model_breast.predict(final)
    output='{0:.{1}f}'.format(prediction[0][1], 2)

    if output==str(4):
        return render_template('../static/form.html',pred='The cancer type is MALIGNANT'
                                                       '\n This particular cell is cancerous. You belong to class: {}'.format(output))
    else:
        return render_template('../static/form.html',pred='The cancer type is BENIGN'
                                                       '\n This particular cell is NOT cancerous. You belong to class: {}'.format(output))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host=config['host'],port=config['port'])
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obqAW.png)

Comment: In your command prompt, run this `python -m pip install scikit-learn`

Comment: I installed the scikit package, still it is showing the same error

Comment: Check the loaded model with sample data and see if it properly loaded into flask app. And make sure to activate any virtualenv if you are using it.

Comment: @HArdRese7 Can you please be more clear about what you are saying.

Answer (score 2):

`'sklearn.svm._classes'` is specific to version 0.19.2 of the scikit-learn package.

You can install this version using:

```
pip install scikit-learn==0.19.2
```